# What is the time complexity of Java StringTokenizer.countTokens()

Tags: java, string

I am hopeful that it has constant time complexity, but the name implies it is actually counting the tokens.

Comment: No, it's not constant time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here's the implementation, if you were curious:

```
public int countTokens() {
    int count = 0;
    int currpos = currentPosition;
    while (currpos < maxPosition) {
        currpos = skipDelimiters(currpos);
        if (currpos >= maxPosition)
            break;
        currpos = scanToken(currpos);
        count++;
    }
    return count;
}
```

I'm not too familiar with `StringTokenizer`, but assuming `maxPosition` can change (which it looks like it can), then it's not constant-time.  You also have to take into account the complexities of `skipDelimiters` and `scanToken`.

Comment: Beat me to it ;)

Answer (score 3):

The api for OpenJDK says:
http://www.docjar.com/html/api/java/util/StringTokenizer.java.html

```
public int countTokens() {
    int count = 0;
    int currpos = currentPosition;

    while (currpos < maxPosition) {    
         currpos = skipDelimiters(currpos);  
         if (currpos >= maxPosition)   
            break;    

         currpos = scanToken(currpos);    
         count++;    
     }    
     return count; 
 }
```

So yes, it is linear time.

Comment: "*So yes*" - OP asked whether it's constant-time. I guess *no* would be correct here. Only a minor note though.

Comment: Yeah, I interpreted the hopeful... but as “can you confirm doubt”

Answer (score 0):

No it's not constant time, it's `ω(n)` where `n` is the length of the string.

A naive implementation of StringTokenizer should take `O(n * d)` where `n` is the length of string and `d` is the number of delimiters.